# Creating a Range at a specific point

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to create a range, which leads to a specific point in the text, but this was very difficult with the ChildNodes, because you can't reach exactly one point in the text, but only for example the beginning or end of a ChildNode.
I there a way to reach the point between „te“ and „st“ (like putting the cursor between „te`|`st“) or is it possible to create a range independent of the childnodes?

*Here is my Code:*

```js
function myFunction(el) {
    var textNode = el.childNodes[1];
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(el);
    range.setStart(textNode, 0);
    range.setEnd(textNode, 0);
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="myText" contenteditable>test<br>test</div>

<button type="button" onclick='myFunction(document.getElementById("myText"))'>Go into Text</button>

</body>
</html>
```

#### Thank you for every help!

Comment: it's a little unclear what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Isn't that what the offset arguments to `setStart` and `setEnd` are for?

Comment: or is it possible to create a range without using „ChildNodes“?

Comment: Do you want the cursor(i.e, `|` ) between `test` like this te`|`st

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/yak613/oum0pdr1/)?